# JavaScript object gets sorted automatically

Tags: javascript, arrays

When I try to add an Object it just automatically sorts it, which I don't want

```
console.log(hwidList.csgo)

hwidList.csgo[hwidList.csgo.length] = { "HWID": 3267523467, "Name": "NewUser2", "ID": 34645674573464, "Date": "04/01/2021:22:47:59" };
console.log(hwidList.csgo)
```

It sorts it alphabetical

[image: It sorts it alphabetical]

Help please

Edit: Thanks for the help! It's the browser / console.log which shows it sorted but it isn't.

[Image of it in terminal and it's not sorted](https://i.stack.imgur.com/42mqR.png)

Comment: If order matters, then an object is the wrong data structure. Consider using an Array or [Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map).

Comment: Objects don't really have sorting order in JS. There is consistent implementation of this amongst the JS engines but it's not defined in the standards so don't rely on it.

Comment: so you need to figure correct index of your array if order matters, if not just use push method

Comment: @Dominik [The order is defined.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5525795/does-javascript-guarantee-object-property-order)

Comment: @iota please link to the spec for it. I can't find the order spec in your linked question

Comment: @Dominik [relevant question for object property order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30076219/does-es6-introduce-a-well-defined-order-of-enumeration-for-object-properties) it has most spec links, if not, you can find it in the spec pretty fast.

Comment: @Dominik You can look for it on ecma-international.org. Here is one relevant method: http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-ordinary-object-internal-methods-and-internal-slots-ownpropertykeys

Comment: This is great, thank you @iota

Comment: @Dominik No problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What browser are you using? For example, in Firefox, when calling `console.log` the result is printed alphabetically for your convenience. This issue has nothing to do with JavaScript or your code, it is the browser trying to help you in the instance you have very large objects.

Comment: First of all thank you for your quick response didn't expect that.
Yes I tested it with firefox.

I am not quite convinced that its the browsers fault.

I tried it with chrome and microsoft edge aswell but no luck

[In Chrome][1]
[In Edge][2]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/lbC1E.png
  [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ohPjs.png

Comment: I can confidently assure you this is the browser trying to help you. Additionally, as other comments have stated if order matters you are using a fundamentally incorrect data structure. 

If you found my answer helpful and answers your question, can you please accept?